# How to insert text inside of arrow icon

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

i created an left and right arrow icons with yes and no text but is displaying beside of arrow icons.Now my task is text inserted in in-line arrow icons.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content login-modal">
        <div class="modal-header login-modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
             <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="modallabel">Confirm</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="text-center">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="login-tab">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <br />
                        <label for="NO">NO</label>
                        <i class=" pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i>
                        <label for="YES">YES</label>
                        <i class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to place your arrows inside a container with position relative. Then set your arrows position to absolute. and place them where you want. Something like this would work...

```
<label for="NO" style="position:relative;">
   <i class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;"></i>
NO</label>
```